# How do I position a node at the top of a neato diagram?

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

Is it possible to coerce graphviz to place **node "a"** at the top of this diagram? I've tried **neato** and **fdp**.

```
digraph G {
    "a";
    "b";
    "c";
    "d";
    "e";
    "a" -> "b";
    "a" -> "d";
    "a" -> "a";
    "b" -> "c";
    "c" -> "d";
    "d" -> "e";
    "e" -> "a";
}
```

[image: neato diagram]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use neato, you may experiment with the `pos` attribute:

```
digraph G {
    "a" [pos="0,2!"];
    "b";
    "c";
    "d";
    "e";
    "a" -> "b";
    "a" -> "d";
    "a" -> "a";
    "b" -> "c";
    "c" -> "d";
    "d" -> "e";
    "e" -> "a";
}
```

When using the `dot` layout, you may switch around the direction of an edge to ensure that `a` stays on top:

```
digraph G {
    "a";
    "b";
    "c";
    "d";
    "e";
    "a" -> "b";
    "a" -> "d";
    "a" -> "a";
    "b" -> "c";
    "c" -> "d";
    "d" -> "e";
    "a" -> "e" [dir=back];
}
```